# What does $\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x) <0$ mean in an optimization problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, gradient-descent

i have the following optimization: $$\min_x f(x) \\ \mathrm{s.t}: x\ge0 , ~ \|x\|_0=1$$ and $x ~\mathrm{is}~ n \times 1$, and $f(x) \ge 0$ as it is $\|.\|^2$.

Meaning that i want to minimize f(x) using only one dimension of $x$. One way is to solve the optimization for each dimension $(x_i)$ separately and take the best one with smallest $f(x_i)$.

But based on some intuition, for an initial point $x$ i check $$\{i:\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x) <0\}$$ and then would choose the dimension $i$ from the above set which has smallest $\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x)$ and then solve the optimization only for that dimension. 
I noticed if $f(x)$ is convex the result is optimum.

But i really like to know the mathematical logic behind it! as:

1-why should $\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x)$ be negative?

2- why to take the dimension with the smallest $\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x)$ in $x$?

Is it because $f(x) \ge 0$? or also the fact that i look for $x \ge 0$ solutions?

Comment: What was $\lVert x \rVert_0$?.

Comment: zero norm of $\vec{x}$ meaning the number of non-zero elements in $\vec{x}$

Comment: Taking each dimension separately doesn't work since your problem is not convex. What is $f$ here?

Comment: @LinAlg: $f(x)$ is $\|.\|^2$ and it is convex. My concerns are specifically questions 1 and 2 in the described conditions.

Comment: Please do not use $\|x\|_0$. The so-called "zero norm" is _not_ a norm. It is an abuse of notation. Please call it what it is: the cardinality function, or $\mathop{\textrm{card}}(x)$.

Comment: @MichaelGrant: Thank you for the suggestion. BTW, do you have any advice regarding to the solution as well?

Comment: Do you mean $x\geq0$ instead of $x>0$? If $x>0$, the cardinality of $x$ is fixed. If $x \geq 0$, try a mixed integer conic quadratic solver like MOSEK.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, minimum does not exist only infimum exists. This is because the problem is separable, hence we can choose arbitrarily small positive value of some component $x_i$ by setting other components to zero. So the infimum would be zero. Regarding your questions, i dont see why your method works, but i try to answer generically.

I think you should consider this set $\{i:-\nabla_{x_{i}} f(x) <0\}$ also observe that gradients are always positive. The first question is due to that fact that negative gradient pushes you to decrease the objective. Since your $x\geq 0$ the gradient would be always positive, hence negative gradient pushes towards all components being zero.  Similar to coordinate descent, you function can be shown to decrease the objective the most if you choose the gradient which is very high i.e negative gradient is smallest thus results in highest decrement of objective.

Comment: 1- Maybe it works for me due to the special data i have.  2- Why do you say the gradient should be always positive?? consider $f(x)=(5-x)^2$ for $x=1$. The function can be always positive but doesn't impose any general limit on the sign of the gradient!!

Comment: I thought your function is squared 2-norm. For a general function it makes sense to consider the highest positive gradient and do the coordinate gradient descent. Well actually not the highest positive gradient it would be better to consider which provides maximum difference between the iterate vs projected iterate (this idea is similar to Greedy coordinate descent).